# Can not upgrade nuclide package to 0.125.0 on atom

Tags: atom-editor, nuclide-editor

Info

```
$ apm -v
apm  1.6.0
npm  2.13.3
node 0.10.40
python 2.7.10
git 2.6.4

$ apm update
Package Updates Available (1)
└── nuclide 0.124.0 -> 0.125.0
Would you like to install these updates? (yes)
```

Error:

```
npm WARN engine nuclide@0.125.0: wanted: {"atom":">=1.5.3","node":">=4.1.1"} (current: {"node":"0.10.40","npm":"2.13.3"})
npm ERR! Darwin 15.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "/Users/chandan/.atom/.apm/.apmrc" "--userconfig" "/Users/chandan/.atom/.apmrc" "install" "/private/var/folders/jx/80gvpbb525z56t19l_n172hw0000gn/T/d-116223-40264-1wsir87/package.tgz" "--target=0.34.5" "--arch=x64"
npm ERR! node v0.10.40
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3

npm ERR! version not found: relative-date@1.1.2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/jx/80gvpbb525z56t19l_n172hw0000gn/T/apm-install-dir-116223-40264-17hzbk1/npm-debug.log
```

Please let me know if i am doing something wrong or if there is a workaround on how to upgrade this nuclide package.

Comment: This must be a completely new problem. As of 10 minutes ago I am unable to install nuclide with apm and I am getting this exact same error. Yesterday I was able to install on a VM just fine.

Comment: My Google search with this error message brought up 2 results: 1. This page, and 2. a paste bin from yesterday (time unknown). See here: http://pastebin.com/aYtiA1sw This is clearly a new problem with Nuclide installer/updater as of yesterday.

Comment: I found this issue: https://github.com/facebook/nuclide/issues/423

Comment: Was able to update to 0.126.0 which got released 3 hrs ago, but did receive https://github.com/facebook/nuclide/issues/313 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved.

This error occurred during the infamous ['left-pad' unpublishing](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/03/23/npm_left_pad_chaos/) of March 2016. 'left-pad' received the most mentions, but 'relative-date' was among the packages that were unpublished as well.

This was not a problem in Nuclide itself but rather in the downloading of its dependencies.

Comment: Yes, i was able to upgrade it now. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

For now I built nuclide manually according to this guide: http://nuclide.io/docs/advanced-topics/building-from-source.

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/nuclide.git
cd nuclide
npm install
apm link
```

It has solved the problem for me.